# Default value for bpy.props.CollectionProperty

Tags: python

How to set a default value for `bpy.props.CollectionProperty`?

Let's use the [example](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html#collection-example) in the documentation for an answer.

I tried to set the default value in the `register` function, but neither `bpy.data` nor `bpy.context` is available at that moment.

Comment: There is no default for a collection. By default the collection is empty when first defined.

Comment: Maybe there is a walk-around. I tried to set the default value in the register function, but neither bpy.data nor bpy.context is available at that moment.

Comment: Can you add to question what you want the default to be?  From comment sounds like you want to add a default item on creation. One trick is to add a handler during rego that runs until one "default"  item is added, then removes itself (the handler).

Comment: @batFINGER I've added a solution that worked for me as the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to use application handlers to set the default value for `bpy.props.CollectionProperty`:

- [bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post) to set the default value right
  after the addon registration via `register()` and then remove the
  handler
- [bpy.app.handlers.load_post](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.load_post) with [@persistent](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.persistent) decorator to set the
  default value after any of the following events:

  - opening Blender
  - reloading the start-up file via the keys `Ctrl` `N`
  - opening any Blender file.

Here is the code:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

class MyCollectionItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name", default="Unknown")
    value = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Value", default="Unknown")

def setDefaultCollectionValue():
    myCollection = bpy.context.scene.myCollection
    # set default value if <myCollection> is empty
    if not myCollection:
        collectionItem = myCollection.add()
        collectionItem.name = "Name 1"
        collectionItem.value = "Value 1"
        collectionItem = myCollection.add()
        collectionItem.name = "Name 2"
        collectionItem.value = "Value 2"

# This handler is needed to set the default value for <bpy.context.scene.myCollection>
# right after the addon registration via register()
def onRegister(scene):
    setDefaultCollectionValue()
    # the handler isn't needed anymore, so remove it
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.remove(onRegister)

# This handler is needed to set the default value for <bpy.context.scene.myCollection>
# after any of the following events:
# - opening Blender
# - reloading the start-up file via the keys Ctrl N
# - opening any Blender file
@persistent
def onFileLoaded(scene):
    addDefaultLevels()

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyCollectionItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.myCollection = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MyCollectionItem)
    # adding handlers defined above in the code
    bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_post.append(onRegister)
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(onFileLoaded)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyCollectionItem)
    del bpy.types.Scene.myCollection
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(onFileLoaded)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: This isn't working as excpected :(
It only fires, when I change something in the scene, after registering the addon. What is unfortunate, because I have a collectionProperty that needs a default value and gives me an error without.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hacky, not optimal solution, but I've given up trying alternatives.

Register a preference (better is to use an existing one, so your preferences aren't cluttered)

```py
class Preferences(AddonPreferences):
    example: StringProperty(
        name="foo"
        update=callbackfunc
    )
```

In the callbackfunc, you can populate your CollectionProperty via .add.

Then just change this preference in order to trigger the callback:

```py
bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.example = str(bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.example)
```

Just beware that draw() gets called an awful lot so have some sort of "do we need to update?" function so you don't hammer your CPU/disk.

```py
skipUpdate = False

class MyPanel(Panel):

    def draw(self, context):
        global skipUpdate

        if not skipUpdate:
            bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.example = str(bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.example)
            skipUpdate = True
```

I'm sure with more development time you could find a different callback that doesn't require registering a preference.

(By the way, this seems to be the method Material Library VX uses, which is where I shamefully borrowed it from.)